# syntax for setting html in jquery with frames

Tags: jquery, frames

I have the following jquery sentence in my program:

```
$("#(parent.frames[2].id)").html (Content);
```

In frame 2 there is a string variable called `id` which holds the `id` of the element I want to change. What I want to do is to replace all the `html` of this `id` with the string `Content`.

The console is actually outputing a syntax error `Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #(parent.frames[2].id)`. What should be the correct syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selector is invalid. I assume you mean the `.parent` object of `window`.

Try this instead

```
$("#"+parent.frames[2].id).html(Content);
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally implemented it with javascript:

parent.frames[2].document.getElementById(parent.frames[2].id).innerHTML = Content;